# Pandas - Changing the frequency of a dataframe from daily to hourly, using the values from the corresponding columns

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe with daily values, the columns correspond to measurements for each hour of the day, one column for each hour. Instead I want to resample the values from daily to hourly and reduce the number of columns to just 1. However I'm at a complete loss at how to do this.

[image]

Comment: What do you expect? A mean value ? Max value ?

Comment: No, I don't want to aggregate it in any way, just reshape the structure.
Right now I have 24 columns for each day, instead I'd like to have 24 rows for each day, one for each hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get rid of non-hour columns, a solution would be:

```python
result = df.set_index('date')\
    .filter(regex='^h')\
    .stack()\
    .to_frame()

# index values are now tuples such as (2018-01-01, 'h1')
result = result.set_index(result.index.map(
    lambda idx: idx[0] + timedelta(hours=int(idx[1][1:]))
))
```

Comment: Thankyou! that did the trick. I had no idea the stack method existed.

Answer (score 0):

The block of code below creates a new DataFrame with two columns:

- ID: this ID is a combination of the zone_id, date and hour of the day.
- observation: this is the observation belonging to the specific hour (ID).

code:

```
new_data=[]
for index,row in your_DataFrame.iterrows(): 
    zone_id_date=str(row['zone_id'])+'_'+str(row['date']) 
    for hour in range(1,25): 
        ID=zone_id_date+'_h'+str(hour) 
        observation=row['h'+str(hour)] 
        new_row=[ID,observation] 
        new_data.append(new_row) 

output_data=pandas.DataFrame(data=new_data, columns = ['ID', 'observation'])
```